# How do I get the amount of entries in a map in Go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the amount of entries in a map in Go. Is there a better way than:

```
count := 0
for key := range mymap {
    count++
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The len function works well for this:

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity

Comment: You answered your question in less than 1 minute :) Why did you ask it then ?

Comment: It took me a few minutes to find the answer in the Go docs, and I didn't see this question answered on SO, so I figured I would try to save other programmers some time.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Stackoverflow encourages such questions and answers. It is knowledge base site, after all, why prohibit anyone from sharing their knowledge?